# How can I see when a view was modified in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I wonder if I can (and I'm pretty sure I can) see the log about when my particular view `A` had lastly been modified/edited, or accessed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find out when your view was last modified, you can use the view USER_OBJECTS:

```
select object_name, object_type, created, last_ddl_time 
from user_objects
where object_name = '<my_view_name>';
```

I'm not sure whether there exists a possibility to find out when your view was last accessed, though.

Comment: Thank you, it helped.
it would be nice if some will say how/where to see the last access time.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle does not track access counts by default.  However, if you are in Oracle 10g or newer, you can leverage Fine Grain Auditing and track the events against the view you'd like to see like selects or even DML statements.

http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/database-security-enhancements-10g.php#fga